# what is for formal explanation of MSS negotiation?

Tags: networking, tcp, mss

I have been trying to find the formal mechanism of MSS negotiation however, cant seem to uncover it.

"MSS negotiation uses the MTU of a local network." is all i can find, however, this does not explain what happens.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc879

Comment: MSS is not negotiated. Each side simply sends the MSS it is willing to receive in the TCP handshake. There is no negotiation, it is dictated.

Comment: See _[RFC 793, Transmission Control Protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793)_: "_Maximum Segment Size Option Data: 16 bits - If this option is present, then it communicates the maximum receive segment size at the TCP which sends this segment. This field must only be sent in the initial connection request (i.e., in segments with the SYN control bit set).  If this option is not used, any segment size is allowed._"